# How to create custom image view like custom list view?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, custom-lists

I want to make one application which contains multiple choice question. Each question has three option. I want to show that option with one background image. And also want to change the color of that image randomly for each question. How can i do that?

It is possible to create list view by putting differnt background image for each row?

**Result.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearlayoutans"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chrono"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_ans_true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#000000" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_ans_1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#000000" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_ans_2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="#000000" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You really ought to research and try a little first.  Ideally post a snippet of code you tried.

Comment: yes by extending imageview you can create customized imageview, Also it is also possible different row color for each rows.

Comment: @donfede  Right now i tried this by taking three text view with background image.

Comment: @donfede I have added my code. In this three text view i am getting threee option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible to create list view by putting differnt background
>   image for each row?

Yes. Take a look at [articles on the internet](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) that back a listview with a custom adapter and a custom view. This is done from the `getView()` method and there is no shortage of examples / tutorials out there.